# Composite class containing a List<AnotherClass>

Tags: c#, list, collections

I would like to have a class that contains all of the other details about the noun I am representing in my software.

```
public class Customer
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<Note> Notes { get; set; } 
}

public class Note
{
  public string Notes { get; set; }
  public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
}
```

I use a SqlCommand to get the data from two different stored procedures in the entry point or button click - it doesn't matter, an example is below....

```
static List<Note> notes = new List<Note>();
static string conString = "Server=localhost;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True;";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetCustomerNotes", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
con.Open();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
cmd.Parameters["@CustomerId"].Value = 1;
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();    

while (reader.Read())
{
   Note note = new Note(
          (string)reader["Notes"].ToString(),
          DateTime.Parse(reader["DateAdded"].ToString())
      );

      notes.Add(note);
}
```

This is all pretty standard stuff....

Here is my question.  Once I get the data for my Customer object I would like to include all notes from my Note object for this Customer in only single class/object: Customer.  So how do I do that?

Executing the same code for the Customer table I tried using a foreach loop to no avail...

```
while (reader.Read())
{
  // removed because this is the same code as above with a diff sproc
  Customer customer = new Customer();

  customer.Name = (string)reader["Name"];

}

foreach (Note note in notes)
    customer.Notes = note;
  // ERROR HERE --> 
  Error 4   Cannot implicitly convert type 'Note' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Note>'
```

So I am a little unclear o how to do this.

Help please.

Comment: How about `customer.Notes = notes`? Whats wrong with that? Do you need a deep copy or something?

Comment: Either `customer.Notes = notes` or `customer.Notes.Add(note)`

Answer (score 0):

if you want add note to Notes (if it is a collection of List< Notes > ), you can add this way:

```
 customer.Notes.Add(note);
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that even though the Customer object had been instantiated, the Notes class, which was a member of the Customer class, also needed to be created so I created a method call to get the collection of notes.

First, I created a function to get the notes....

```
static List<Note> GetCustomerNotes()
{
  Customer c = new Customer();
  c.Notes = new List<Note>();

  foreach (Note note in notes)
    c.Notes.Add(note);

  return c.Notes;
}
```

Then I called this function in my overloaded constructor...

```
while (reader.Read())
{          
   Customer customer = new Customer(
      (string)reader["Name"],
      GetCustomerNotes()
  );
}
```